# 'Component' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I created one component and I'm exporting it

```
import React , {Component} from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg';

class Item extends Component {
     
  render () {
    return (
    
       <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">ReactND - Coding Practice</h1>
        </header>
        <h2>Shopping List</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter New Item"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button disabled={this.inputIsEmpty()}>Add</button>
        </form>

        <button onClick={this.deleteLastItem} disabled={this.noItemsFound()}>
          Delete Last Item
        </button>
        </div>
    )  
  }
}

export default Item
```

And I want to use this component in my app component as below

```
import React from 'react';
import './Item';

class App extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
        <div>      
        <Item />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But I got this error in App.js

```
 Line 9:  'Item' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
```

pretty sure I did everything. I have exported and imported this component , so what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to name your import.

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from './Item';

class App extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
        <div>      
        <Item />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```